# How to shorten appending to different lists depending on the outcome of if statement

Tags: python, list, refactoring

Any idea if it's possible to shorten and prettify this one (an extra variant assumes nested if-else conditions and more lists)?

```py
some_list, some_other_list = [], []
if condition:
    some_list.append(value)
else:
    some_other_list.append(value)
```

Comment: Where does this question comes from? What is the bigger problem?

Comment: Seems related to code review not to an actual problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ternary expression:

```
(some_list if condition else some_other_list).append(value)
```

Explanation:

```
>>> condition = True
>>> ("A" if condition else "B")
A

>>> condition = False
>>> ("A" if condition else "B")
B
```

Comment: Nice one, upvoted and it should be the accepted answer, but an explanation would make it even better.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use ternary.

```
some_list.append(value) if condition else some_other_list.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little variation:

```
(condition and some_other_list or some_list).append(value)
```

**OR**:

For Python versions lower then 2.5, Tuple/lambda approach:

```
((lambda: some_other_list.append(value), lambda: some_list.append(value))[condition]())
```

**Explanation**:

```
condition = True

some_list = []
some_other_list = []
value = 5

((lambda: some_other_list.append(value), lambda: some_list.append(value))[condition]())

print(some_list)             # 5
print(some_other_list)
```

Comment: About the first option: what if `condition == True`, but `some_other_list` is empty?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog assuming it is, the exp. goes for the first part as well.

Comment: Okay, but now what if `some_other_list` isn't empty? `condition == True` would yield `some_other_list` instead of `some_list`.